# is there a function to generates the code again, or better ideas?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I created a module that calculates the cost for breakfast, lunch and dinner in one day, I need to compute it again for other days (day 2, day 3 ...) without needing to copy the code again,so we can enter as many days as we want, is there any suggession to do it
my module looks like:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm

class daily_allowances(orm.Model):

    def _compute_breakfast(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
        x = {}
        for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context):
            x[record.id] = record.breakfast_allowances - record.breakfast_cost
        return x

    def _compute_lunch(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
        x = {}
        for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context):
            x[record.id] = record.lunch_allowances - record.lunch_cost
        return x

    def _compute_dinner(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
        x = {}
        for record in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context):
            x[record.id] = record.dinner_allowances - record.dinner_cost
        return x


    _name = 'daily.allowances'
    _columns = {
        'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', string="Employee Name", required=True),
        'trip_date': fields.date('date of the trip', required=False),       
        'daily_allowances': fields.float('Daily Allowances', required=False),
        'breakfast_allowances': fields.float('Breakfast Allowances', required=False),
        'breakfast_date': fields.datetime('Date', required=False),
        'brekfast_cost': fields.float('Costed', required=False),
        'breakfast_remaining': fields.function(_compute_breakfast, store=True,string='Breakfast Balance'),
        'lunch_allowances': fields.float('Lunch Allowances', required=False),
        'lunch_date': fields.datetime('Date', required=False),
        'lunch_cost': fields.float('Costed', required=False),
        'lunch_remaining': fields.function(_compute_breakfast, store=True,string='Breakfast Balance'),
        'dinner_allowances': fields.float('Dinner Allowances', required=False),
        'dinner_date': fields.datetime('Date', required=False),
        'dinner_cost': fields.float('Costed', required=False),
        'dinner_remaining': fields.function(_compute_breakfast, store=True,string='Breakfast Balance'),
       }
```

Comment: You should make a one scheduled  action (croan job) and set the Interval Unit as "Day" . so that system will automatically call your function based on your settled Interval Unit. I think this way is better to do your job

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you have a good example of how to create cron job?

Comment: @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa: Using a scheduled job will not help as each record has to have the actual cost for the meal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your module is set up to keep track of per diems on a daily basis.  This means that you will need to create a new record for each day, for each employee, and enter in the amounts of what they spent for each meal.

This seems fine.

One observation:  you have a `trip_date` field, so you don't need `breakfast_date`, `lunch_date`, nor `dinner_date` fields -- they should all be the same.

If you need more help you will to show us how you call this code, and the xml view file.

Comment: thanks for the answer but what if the trip is one week long, I need to calculate the cost for the whole trip

Comment: @RamiWafai: If the trip is one week long then you will need an entry (a record) for each day -- unless your employees spend exactly the same amount for every breakfast, exactly the same amount for every lunch, and exactly the same amount for every dinner?